# Tridion content services has alot of open sessions with database

Tags: sites-9.1, content-service, opentelemetry

While integrating [opentelemetry](https://opentelemetry.io/) with tridion content.svc, we realized that there are a lot of broken spans in the [Jaeger](https://www.jaegertracing.io/) UI. After a bit of investigation, we suspected that the trace spans are set to a certain limit hence we increased that in opentelemetry configuration - BUT this did not solve the issue.

We then moved forward investigation more and realized that when content.svc is called for eg:

```
/client/v2/content.svc/Publications(27)/Keywords?$filter=(TaxonomyId%20e
q%2040)&$expand=Components&$format=json
```

it has alot of **NullPointerException** reported:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException 
        at com.tridion.cache.CacheChannel.isServiceValid(CacheChannel.java:369) 
        at com.tridion.cache.CacheChannel.isCachingAllowed(CacheChannel.java:380) 
        at com.tridion.cache.BroadcastCache.isCachingAllowed(BroadcastCache.java:127) 
        at com.tridion.cache.BroadcastCache.put(BroadcastCache.java:36) 
        at com.tridion.storage.caching.CachedQueryDAO.listQuery(CachedQueryDAO.java:62) 
        at com.sdl.web.content.odata.input.jpql.JPQLExecutor.execute(JPQLExecutor.java:154) 
        at 
com.sdl.web.content.resolver.PublicationsResolver.resolveEntry(PublicationsResolver.java:62) 
        at com.sdl.web.content.odata.input.resolver.ResolverBase.resolve(ResolverBase.java:88) 
        at 
com.sdl.web.content.odata.input.resolver.ResolverBase.getPreviousResolved(ResolverBase.java:20
3) 
        at com.sdl.web.content.odata.input.resolver.ResolverBase.resolve(ResolverBase.java:65) 
        at 
com.sdl.web.content.odata.input.handler.ODataFeedRenderer.renderODataFeed(ODataFeedRenderer.ja
va:57) 
        at 
com.sdl.web.content.odata.input.handler.ODataWebHandler.handleODataEntity(ODataWebHandler.java
:207) 
        at 
com.sdl.web.content.odata.input.handler.ODataWebHandler.handleResourceRequest(ODataWebHandler.
java:178) 
        at 
com.sdl.web.content.controller.ContentV2Controller.handleResourceRequest(ContentV2Controller.j
ava:92) 
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) 
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) 
        at 
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) 
        at 
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.
java:190) 
        at 
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandle
rMethod.java:138) 
        at 
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndH
andle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104) 
        at 
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandl
erMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:892) 
        at 
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInter
nal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797) 
        at 
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandler
MethodAdapter.java:87) 
        at 
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1039) 
        at 
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942) 
        at 
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005) 
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:897) 
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634) 
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882) 
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) 
        at 
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:2
31) 
        at 
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) 
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) 
        at 
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:1
93) 
        at 
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) 
        at 
org.springframework.boot.actuate.web.trace.servlet.HttpTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpTraceF
ilter.java:88) 
        at 
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109) 
        at 
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:1
93) 
        at 
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
```

We first thought that this is something with our configuration (still not sure) but we did not find anything significant.

We looked deepper into opentelemetry logs and found that every single orphan span  (the ones that  referenced missing parent span) that appeared in Jaeger UI is at Hibernate database operations.

We then realized that this might be happening due to open hibernate sessions because OpenTelemetry reports spans for sessions only when a session is closed. This way it can measure the time it took for a Hibernate session and all of the database operations executed within that session. If a session is never closed, it simply will not report it.

and we concluded that - the corresponding Hibernate session was not reported for all those database operations during the service call.

We decided to reproduce  similar behavior in a sample Hibernate project and we also
managed to get the same result by  throwing an exception  before the closing of Hibernate
session and not handling it on purpose.

We also analyzed trace for that call and within that call, Tridion Content  Service has executed
5855 database statements  out  of which 78 were reported without sessions  (so presumably
their session was not closed correctly and therefore was not  reported to OpenTelemetry
collector)

The only way for us to see all these exceptions is by enabling debug  logging in the
OpenTelemetry Java agent. Without this setting, we don’t see those errors anywhere.  That
could indicate that the exception is caught somewhere above and is not printed, but,
because the OpenTelemetry agent intercepts and wraps the call, it is able to get it and print it.

Please let us know what could be the issue?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the issue - yes, there are a lot of NPE's you're seeing, and it seems to be deep within Hibernate. Are you actually seeing issues because of this, is this maybe normal with how Hibernate manages pooled sessions? Is your database running out of available connections? Is the connection pool depleted? What I'm trying to say is that perhaps that's how Hibernate handles it? (I am not sure, and quite curious about it now too).

Comment: Hey Nuno, I am not sure either, but would love to deep dive with any inputs I have to look forward into it. The current issue relates to cache channel service ( at com.tridion.cache.CacheChannel.isServiceValid) somewhere and I am not sure if hibernate leaves a connection open  on purpose. Also, I might be wrong but I also see alot of queries to DB for a simple content.svc call. It might be a question for support though but just saying if it could be related.

Comment: OK. A single content service call _could_ trigger lots of queries, depending on the information requested (the example you have is taxonomy which could be DB heavy) but as you say that's perhaps more for support to look into.

Comment: Yeah understandble. An open db session (for a longer period) could be a performance bottleneck, indeed something that support should be able to explain. anyone else has further inputs?

Comment: use the MS SQL Profile Tracing tool to capture your SQL query to see what it's going on. as @Nuno mentioned just for one data query in the backend it will be multiple SQL queries joining to get the response what it's expected.

Comment: Yeah I understand that. Also even in case of lazy loading the sessions should close after a while which is not happening, but may be trace would explain if sessions are getting closed after the opentelemtry sends off data to Jaeger UI. will update more later.