# Tridion content service generate a massive amount of small database queries

Tags: database, content-service, opentelemetry

This is a follow up question from [Tridion content services has alot of open sessions with database](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/21768/tridion-content-services-has-alot-of-open-sessions-with-database).
Original question was about dropped spans and unclosed Hibernate sessions. But the data comes out of the same investigation so I decided to create a separate question.

When we looked into OpenTelemetry traces for Tridion content service we saw a massive amount of database queries. The highest number we have seen is 5604 db calls and the request takes up to 45 seconds to complete.
I have generated a histogram and I can provide the most executed queries. OpenTelemetry logs every single database statement and I can see all of them in Jaeger but without actual values (only placeholders).
When I checked the most common queries in that request I saw that those were for CUSTOM_META and KEYWORD_RELATIONS table. The first time I stumbled on that trace I suspected that there might be `@OneToMany` annotations with `FetchType.EAGER` as this could explain such a massive amount of queries.

I put here the analysis of the two traces.

### First trace

Total db statements: 2808

Response time: 18 seconds

Most common db statements in that request

```
2488 statements (88.6%) : select custommeta0_.PUBLICATION_ID as PUBLICAT9_10_0_, custommeta0_.NAMESPACE_ID as NAMESPAC8_10_0_, custommeta0_.ITEM_ID as ITEM_ID4_10_0_, custommeta0_.CUSTOM_META_VALUE_ID as CUSTOM_M1_10_0_, custommeta0_.CUSTOM_META_VALUE_ID as CUSTOM_M1_10_1_, custommeta0_.KEY_DATE_VALUE as KEY_DATE2_10_1_, custommeta0_.KEY_FLOAT_VALUE as KEY_FLOA3_10_1_, custommeta0_.ITEM_ID as ITEM_ID4_10_1_, custommeta0_.ITEM_TYPE as ITEM_TYP5_10_1_, custommeta0_.KEY_NAME as KEY_NAME6_10_1_, custommeta0_.KEY_TYPE as KEY_TYPE7_10_1_, custommeta0_.NAMESPACE_ID as NAMESPAC8_10_1_, custommeta0_.PUBLICATION_ID as PUBLICAT9_10_1_, custommeta0_.KEY_STRING_LOB_VALUE as KEY_STR10_10_1_, custommeta0_.KEY_STRING_VALUE as KEY_STR11_10_1_ from CUSTOM_META custommeta0_ where custommeta0_.PUBLICATION_ID=? and custommeta0_.NAMESPACE_ID=? and custommeta0_.ITEM_ID=?

320 statements (11.4%) : select componentm0_.PUBLICATION_ID as PUBLICAT1_13_, componentm0_.NAMESPACE_ID as NAMESPAC2_13_, componentm0_.ITEM_REFERENCE_ID as ITEM_REF3_13_, componentm0_1_.CREATION_DATE as CREATION4_13_, componentm0_1_.INITIAL_PUBLICATION_DATE as INITIAL_5_13_, componentm0_1_.ITEM_SELECTOR as ITEM_SEL6_13_, componentm0_1_.ITEM_TYPE as ITEM_TYP7_13_, componentm0_1_.LAST_PUBLISHED_DATE as LAST_PUB8_13_, componentm0_1_.MAJOR_VERSION as MAJOR_VE9_13_, componentm0_1_.MINOR_VERSION as MINOR_V10_13_, componentm0_1_.MODIFICATION_DATE as MODIFIC11_13_, componentm0_1_.OWNING_PUBLICATION_ID as OWNING_12_13_, componentm0_1_.TITLE as TITLE13_13_, componentm0_1_.TRUSTEE as TRUSTEE14_13_, componentm0_.IS_MULTIMEDIA as IS_MULTI1_4_, componentm0_.SCHEMA_ID as SCHEMA_I2_4_ from COMPONENT componentm0_ inner join ITEMS componentm0_1_ on componentm0_.PUBLICATION_ID=componentm0_1_.PUBLICATION_ID and componentm0_.NAMESPACE_ID=componentm0_1_.NAMESPACE_ID and componentm0_.ITEM_REFERENCE_ID=componentm0_1_.ITEM_REFERENCE_ID cross join ITEM_CATEGORIES_AND_KEYWORDS relatedkey1_ where componentm0_.NAMESPACE_ID=? and componentm0_.PUBLICATION_ID=? and componentm0_.NAMESPACE_ID=relatedkey1_.NAMESPACE_ID and componentm0_.PUBLICATION_ID=relatedkey1_.PUBLICATION_ID and componentm0_.ITEM_REFERENCE_ID=relatedkey1_.ITEM_REFERENCE_ID and relatedkey1_.KEYWORD_ID=? and relatedkey1_.TAXONOMY_ID=?
```

### Second trace

Total db statements: 5604

Response time: 45 seconds

Most common db statements in that request

```
1547 statements (27.6%) : select custommeta0_.PUBLICATION_ID as PUBLICAT9_10_0_, custommeta0_.NAMESPACE_ID as NAMESPAC8_10_0_, custommeta0_.ITEM_ID as ITEM_ID4_10_0_, custommeta0_.CUSTOM_META_VALUE_ID as CUSTOM_M1_10_0_, custommeta0_.CUSTOM_META_VALUE_ID as CUSTOM_M1_10_1_, custommeta0_.KEY_DATE_VALUE as KEY_DATE2_10_1_, custommeta0_.KEY_FLOAT_VALUE as KEY_FLOA3_10_1_, custommeta0_.ITEM_ID as ITEM_ID4_10_1_, custommeta0_.ITEM_TYPE as ITEM_TYP5_10_1_, custommeta0_.KEY_NAME as KEY_NAME6_10_1_, custommeta0_.KEY_TYPE as KEY_TYPE7_10_1_, custommeta0_.NAMESPACE_ID as NAMESPAC8_10_1_, custommeta0_.PUBLICATION_ID as PUBLICAT9_10_1_, custommeta0_.KEY_STRING_LOB_VALUE as KEY_STR10_10_1_, custommeta0_.KEY_STRING_VALUE as KEY_STR11_10_1_ from CUSTOM_META custommeta0_ where custommeta0_.PUBLICATION_ID=? and custommeta0_.NAMESPACE_ID=? and custommeta0_.ITEM_ID=?

995 statements (17.8%) : select keywordrel0_.NODE as NODE2_15_0_, keywordrel0_.KEYWORD_TO as KEYWORD_1_15_0_, keywordrel0_.KEYWORD_TO as KEYWORD_1_15_1_, keywordrel0_.NODE as NODE2_15_1_ from KEYWORD_RELATIONS keywordrel0_ where keywordrel0_.NODE=?

897 statements (16.0%) : select keyword0_.NODE_ID as NODE_ID2_26_, keyword0_.FACET_ISABSTRACT as FACET_IS3_26_, keyword0_.FACET_DEPTH as FACET_DE4_26_, keyword0_.FACET_HASCHILDREN as FACET_HA5_26_, keyword0_.FACET_ID as FACET_ID6_26_, keyword0_.FACET_ITEMTYPE as FACET_IT7_26_, keyword0_.FACET_KEY as FACET_KE8_26_, keyword0_.FACET_LEFT as FACET_LE9_26_, keyword0_.NAMESPACE_ID as NAMESPA10_26_, keyword0_.FACET_ISNAVIGABLE as FACET_I11_26_, keyword0_.FACET_PARENT as FACET_P12_26_, keyword0_.PUBLICATION_ID as PUBLICA13_26_, keyword0_.FACET_RIGHT as FACET_R14_26_, keyword0_.TAXONOMY_ID as TAXONOM15_26_, keyword0_.TOTAL_RELATEDITEMS as TOTAL_R16_26_, keyword0_.FACET_DESCRIPTION as FACET_D17_26_, keyword0_.FACET_NAME as FACET_N18_26_, keyword0_.FACET_ISUSEDFORIDENTIFICATION as FACET_I19_26_ from TAXFACETS keyword0_ where keyword0_.ITEM_SELECTOR=? and keyword0_.PUBLICATION_ID=? and keyword0_.NAMESPACE_ID=? and keyword0_.TAXONOMY_ID=? and keyword0_.FACET_ID=?

575 statements (10.3%) : select componentm0_.PUBLICATION_ID as PUBLICAT1_13_, componentm0_.NAMESPACE_ID as NAMESPAC2_13_, componentm0_.ITEM_REFERENCE_ID as ITEM_REF3_13_, componentm0_1_.CREATION_DATE as CREATION4_13_, componentm0_1_.INITIAL_PUBLICATION_DATE as INITIAL_5_13_, componentm0_1_.ITEM_SELECTOR as ITEM_SEL6_13_, componentm0_1_.ITEM_TYPE as ITEM_TYP7_13_, componentm0_1_.LAST_PUBLISHED_DATE as LAST_PUB8_13_, componentm0_1_.MAJOR_VERSION as MAJOR_VE9_13_, componentm0_1_.MINOR_VERSION as MINOR_V10_13_, componentm0_1_.MODIFICATION_DATE as MODIFIC11_13_, componentm0_1_.OWNING_PUBLICATION_ID as OWNING_12_13_, componentm0_1_.TITLE as TITLE13_13_, componentm0_1_.TRUSTEE as TRUSTEE14_13_, componentm0_.IS_MULTIMEDIA as IS_MULTI1_4_, componentm0_.SCHEMA_ID as SCHEMA_I2_4_ from COMPONENT componentm0_ inner join ITEMS componentm0_1_ on componentm0_.PUBLICATION_ID=componentm0_1_.PUBLICATION_ID and componentm0_.NAMESPACE_ID=componentm0_1_.NAMESPACE_ID and componentm0_.ITEM_REFERENCE_ID=componentm0_1_.ITEM_REFERENCE_ID cross join ITEM_CATEGORIES_AND_KEYWORDS relatedkey1_ where componentm0_.NAMESPACE_ID=? and componentm0_.PUBLICATION_ID=? and componentm0_.NAMESPACE_ID=relatedkey1_.NAMESPACE_ID and componentm0_.PUBLICATION_ID=relatedkey1_.PUBLICATION_ID and componentm0_.ITEM_REFERENCE_ID=relatedkey1_.ITEM_REFERENCE_ID and relatedkey1_.KEYWORD_ID=? and relatedkey1_.TAXONOMY_ID=?

563 statements (10.0%) : select custommeta0_.CUSTOM_META_VALUE_ID as CUSTOM_M1_10_, custommeta0_.KEY_DATE_VALUE as KEY_DATE2_10_, custommeta0_.KEY_FLOAT_VALUE as KEY_FLOA3_10_, custommeta0_.ITEM_ID as ITEM_ID4_10_, custommeta0_.ITEM_TYPE as ITEM_TYP5_10_, custommeta0_.KEY_NAME as KEY_NAME6_10_, custommeta0_.KEY_TYPE as KEY_TYPE7_10_, custommeta0_.NAMESPACE_ID as NAMESPAC8_10_, custommeta0_.PUBLICATION_ID as PUBLICAT9_10_, custommeta0_.KEY_STRING_LOB_VALUE as KEY_STR10_10_, custommeta0_.KEY_STRING_VALUE as KEY_STR11_10_ from CUSTOM_META custommeta0_ where custommeta0_.NAMESPACE_ID=? and custommeta0_.PUBLICATION_ID=? and custommeta0_.ITEM_ID=? and custommeta0_.ITEM_TYPE=?
```

I suspect that the top ones are caused by the `@OneToMany` annotation with `FetchType.EAGER` as this is a typical picture for that. With that fetch type Hibernate will fetch all related items even if they are not used.
I am also attaching a screenshot of the first trace in Jaeger.

[image]

Comment: I suspect you may get better traction on this via Customer Support, as this is rather low-level for the regular Stack Exchange implementer crowd.

Comment: Unfortunately we cant run profiler as we use Azure SQL. Anyother suggetsions. Could it be vladmihalcea.com/n-plus-1-query-problem ?